# Chainer: AttributeError: module 'chainer.distributions' has no attribute 'Independent'

Tags: chainer

Problem on using API named Independent.

```
I am using --
  Chainer: 5.4.0
NumPy: 1.15.4
CuPy:
  CuPy Version          : 5.4.0
  CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda-10.0
  CUDA Build Version    : 10000
  CUDA Driver Version   : 10010
  CUDA Runtime Version  : 10000
  cuDNN Build Version   : 7401
  cuDNN Version         : 7401
  NCCL Build Version    : 2307
  NCCL Runtime Version  : 2307
  iDeep: 2.0.0.post3
```

Does in version 5.4.0 in Chainer.distribution- Class Independent is removed ?

I tried to use the distribution class directly although requirement of Independent class was required.

I am using the below link model.
 [VAE Network](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/vae/net.py)

I am not using Binary dataset and changed according to my own custom dataset.

```
 chainer/network.py in forward(self, x)
        22 
        23     def forward(self, x):
   ---> 24         q_z = self.encoder(x)
        25         z = q_z.sample(self.k)
        26         p_x = self.decoder(z)

~/anaconda3/envs/chainer_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/link.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         240         if forward is None:
         241             forward = self.forward
     --> 242         out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
         243 
         244         # Call forward_postprocess hook

 chainer/network.py in forward(self, x)
          50         mu = self.mu(h)
          51         ln_sigma = self.ln_sigma(h)  # log(sigma)
     ---> 52         return D.Independent(D.Normal(loc=mu, log_scale=ln_sigma))
          53 
          54
```

*AttributeError: module 'chainer.distributions' has no attribute 'Independent'*

Answer (score 1):

`D.Independent` is a new feature introduced in Chainer v6.0.0. You need to update Chainer.

Comment: Okay. Conda chainer V 6.0.0 is not available .Does I have to install everything manually ?@kmaehashi

Comment: For now, you can use `pip install chainer` instead. I'll ask anaconda guys to update Chainer package (it's maintained by official Anaconda team, not by Chainer team).

Comment: Since, I cannot disturb the recent environment.I want to use Docker, I refer to the upgrade chainer 6.0.0 its not much detail explained . Can u refer to something installing chainer 6.0.0 with Docker. @kmaehashi

Comment: $nvidia-docker run -it chainer/chainer /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'chainer/chainer:latest' locally. Can u give some insight to work it off.

Comment: I have updated anyhow, no longer getting those errors.Thank you @kmaehashi